# Why are indirect bandgap semiconductors opaque?

Tags: optics, semiconductor-physics

It is commonly explained that semiconductors like silicon, germanium, GaAs... are opaque because all of the visible wavelengths are above the band gap so they get absorbed.

However silicon and germanium have indirect bandgaps and require a phonon interaction which should be rare. Why are they not transparent to the human eye?

Comment: Absorption does not require a phonon - an electron can go direct from valence to conduction bands, it just won’t happen at the minimum indirect gap energy.